# scikit-learn: use classifier from older version

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, backwards-compatibility

I have a pickled scikit-learn classifier trained in version 0.14.1, and I want to use it on my mac which has scikit-learn version 0.17.1. When I try to run clf.score I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute '_dual_coef_'
```

Googling this it looks like the problem is with the difference in version between making the classifier and now wanting to test it. If retraining is not an option, is there a way to upgrade the classifier to work in the new version of scikit-learn?

Comment: Not sure if this will solve the problem, but have you tried an intermediate upgrade? For example, unpickle with `sklearn` 0.16 or 0.15 and then pickling the classifier again until it eventually works with 0.17.

Comment: It's pickled with the pickle library, so I don't think the actual pickling itself is the issue.

Comment: I agree that pickling is not the problem, but if you unpickle to an intermediate `sklearn` version there might be a bigger chance of backwards compatibility with the classifier.

Comment: Have you tried installing the old sklearn version in a virtualenv, loading the model and writing it out with joblib. Then try to load it in the latest version?

Comment: No haven't tried outputting from the older version with joblib, I'll have a look.